# Show that $\ker f(T) = \ker d(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm having trouble solving the following question:

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$ with minimal polynomial $p(x)$ over $F$. Let $f(x)$ be any polynomial over $F$ and $d(x)$ be the greatest common divisor of $f(x)$ and $p(x)$. Prove that $\ker f(T) = \ker d(T)$.

Comment: Please make use of the body of the Question to give a full statement of the problem you want help with and provide some context for why the problem is important, interesting or challenging for you.  Simply posting an assigned exercise with no more context than "Please solve this for me, I'm having trouble" will often result in downvoting and/or closure of the Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $d=\gcd(f,p)$, there are polynomials $a,b$ such that $af+bp=d$.

Therefore, $d(T)=a(T)f(T)+b(T)p(T)=a(T)f(T)$.

This implies that if $f(T)x=0$, then $d(T)x=0$. In other words, $\ker(f(T))\subset\ker(d(T))$.

The converse is trivial. Since there is $c$ such that $f=cd$, then $f(T)x=c(T)d(T)x$. Therefore, if $d(T)x=0$, this implies that $f(T)x=0$. In other words $\ker(d(T))\subset \ker(f(T))$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I totally forgot about that theorem.